# Upgrading from reCAPTCHA v1 to v2 - server-side PHP

Tags: php, recaptcha

I have a website that someone else has build. There is a register page that calls PHP which has the below:

```
require_once('inc/func/recaptchalib.php');

// Get a key from https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin/create
$publickey = "XXXXXXX";
$privatekey = "XXXXXXX";

# The response from reCAPTCHA
$resp = null;

# The error code from reCAPTCHA, if any
$error = null;

# Was there a reCAPTCHA response?
if ($_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]) {
        $resp = recaptcha_check_answer(
                    $privatekey,
                    $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                    $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                    $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

        if ($resp->is_valid) {
            //echo "You got it!";
        }
        else {
            # Set the error code so that we can display it
            //$error = $resp->error;

            return "Invalid Verification Code (reenter CAPTCHA code)";
        }
}
else {
    return "Invalid Verification Code (reenter CAPTCHA code)";
}
```

As you can see the script is calling recaptchalib.php which is shown below:

```
<?php
    /*
     * This is a PHP library that handles calling reCAPTCHA.
     *    - Documentation and latest version
     *          http://recaptcha.net/plugins/php/
     *    - Get a reCAPTCHA API Key
     *          https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin/create
     *    - Discussion group
     *          http://groups.google.com/group/recaptcha
     *
     * Copyright (c) 2007 reCAPTCHA -- http://recaptcha.net
     * AUTHORS:
     *   Mike Crawford
     *   Ben Maurer
     *
     * Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
     * of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
     * in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
     * to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
     * copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
     * furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
     *
     * The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
     * all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
     *
     * THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
     * IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
     * FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
     * AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
     * LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
     * OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
     * THE SOFTWARE.
     */

    /**
     * The reCAPTCHA server URLs
     */
    define("RECAPTCHA_API_SERVER", "http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api");
    define("RECAPTCHA_API_SECURE_SERVER", "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api");
    define("RECAPTCHA_VERIFY_SERVER", "www.google.com");

    /**
     * Encodes the given data into a query string format
     * @param $data - array of string elements to be encoded
     * @return string - encoded request
     */
    function _recaptcha_qsencode ($data) {
        $req = "";
        foreach ($data as $key => $value)
            $req .= $key . '=' . urlencode(stripslashes($value)) . '&';

        // Cut the last '&'
        $req = substr($req, 0, strlen($req)-1);
        return $req;
    }


    /**
     * Submits an HTTP POST to a reCAPTCHA server
     * @param string $host
     * @param string $path
     * @param array $data
     * @param int port
     * @return array response
     */
    function _recaptcha_http_post($host, $path, $data, $port = 80) {

        $req = _recaptcha_qsencode ($data);

        $http_request  = "POST $path HTTP/1.0\r\n";
        $http_request .= "Host: $host\r\n";
        $http_request .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;\r\n";
        $http_request .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n";
        $http_request .= "User-Agent: reCAPTCHA/PHP\r\n";
        $http_request .= "\r\n";
        $http_request .= $req;

        $response = '';
        if (false == ( $fs = @fsockopen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr, 10))) {
            die ('Could not open socket');
        }

        fwrite($fs, $http_request);

        while (!feof($fs))
            $response .= fgets($fs, 1160); // One TCP-IP packet

        fclose($fs);
        $response = explode("\r\n\r\n", $response, 2);

        return $response;
    }


    /**
     * Gets the challenge HTML (JavaScript and non-JavaScript  version).
     * This is called from the browser, and the resulting reCAPTCHA HTML widget
     * is embedded within the HTML form it was called from.
     * @param string $pubkey A public key for reCAPTCHA
     * @param string $error The error given by reCAPTCHA (optional, default is null)
     * @param boolean $use_ssl Should the request be made over ssl? (optional, default is false)

     * @return string - The HTML to be embedded in the user's form.
     */
    function recaptcha_get_html ($pubkey, $error = null, $use_ssl = false)
    {
        if ($pubkey == null || $pubkey == '') {
            die ("To use reCAPTCHA you must get an API key from <a href='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin/create'>https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin/create</a>");
        }

        if ($use_ssl) {
            $server = RECAPTCHA_API_SECURE_SERVER;
        }
        else {
            $server = RECAPTCHA_API_SERVER;
        }

        $errorpart = "";
        if ($error) {
            $errorpart = "&amp;error=" . $error;
        }
        return '<script type="text/javascript" src="'.
               $server .
               '/challenge?k=' .
               $pubkey .
               $errorpart .
               '"></script>

               <noscript>
                   <iframe src="'. $server . '/noscript?k=' . $pubkey . $errorpart . '" height="300" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe><br/>
                   <textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40"></textarea>
                   <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field" value="manual_challenge"/>
               </noscript>';
    }


    /**
     * A ReCaptchaResponse is returned from recaptcha_check_answer()
     */
    class ReCaptchaResponse {
        var $is_valid;
        var $error;
    }


    /**
      * Calls an HTTP POST function to verify if the user's
      * guess was correct
      * @param string $privkey
      * @param string $remoteip
      * @param string $challenge
      * @param string $response
      * @param array $extra_params an array of extra variables
      *                            to post to the server
      * @return ReCaptchaResponse
      */
    function recaptcha_check_answer ($privkey, $remoteip, $challenge, $response, $extra_params = array())
    {
        if ($privkey == null || $privkey == '') {
            die ("To use reCAPTCHA you must get an API key from <a href='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin/create'>https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin/create</a>");
        }

        if ($remoteip == null || $remoteip == '') {
            die ("For security reasons, you must pass the remote IP address to reCAPTCHA");
        }

        // Discard spam submissions
        if ($challenge == null ||
            strlen($challenge) == 0 ||
            $response == null ||
            strlen($response) == 0) {

                $recaptcha_response = new ReCaptchaResponse();
                $recaptcha_response->is_valid = false;
                $recaptcha_response->error = 'incorrect-captcha-sol';
                return $recaptcha_response;
        }

        $response = _recaptcha_http_post(
                        RECAPTCHA_VERIFY_SERVER, "/recaptcha/api/verify",
                        array (
                               'privatekey' => $privkey,
                               'remoteip'   => $remoteip,
                               'challenge'  => $challenge,
                               'response'   => $response
                               ) + $extra_params
                        );

        $answers = explode ("\n", $response [1]);
        $recaptcha_response = new ReCaptchaResponse();

        if (trim ($answers [0]) == 'true') {
            $recaptcha_response->is_valid = true;
        }
        else {
            $recaptcha_response->is_valid = false;
            $recaptcha_response->error = $answers [1];
        }
        return $recaptcha_response;
    }

    /**
     * Gets a URL where the user can sign up for reCAPTCHA. If your
     * application has a configuration page where you enter a key,
     * you should provide a link using this function.
     * @param string $domain The domain where the page is hosted
     * @param string $appname The name of your application
     */
    function recaptcha_get_signup_url ($domain = null, $appname = null) {
        return "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin/create?" .
               _recaptcha_qsencode(array('domains' => $domain,
                                         'app' => $appname));
    }

    function _recaptcha_aes_pad($val) {
        $block_size = 16;
        $numpad = $block_size - (strlen ($val) % $block_size);
        return str_pad($val, strlen ($val) + $numpad, chr($numpad));
    }

    /* Mailhide-related code */

    function _recaptcha_aes_encrypt($val, $ky) {
        if (! function_exists ("mcrypt_encrypt")) {
            die ("To use reCAPTCHA Mailhide, you need to have the mcrypt PHP module installed.");
        }
        $mode = MCRYPT_MODE_CBC;
        $enc = MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128;
        $val = _recaptcha_aes_pad($val);
        return mcrypt_encrypt($enc,
                              $ky,
                              $val,
                              $mode,
                              "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0");
    }


    function _recaptcha_mailhide_urlbase64 ($x) {
        return strtr(base64_encode ($x), '+/', '-_');
    }

    /* Gets the reCAPTCHA Mailhide URL for a given email, public
       key and private key */
    function recaptcha_mailhide_url($pubkey, $privkey, $email) {
        if ($pubkey == '' ||
            $pubkey == null ||
            $privkey == "" ||
            $privkey == null) {

            die ("To use reCAPTCHA Mailhide, you have to sign up for a public and private key, " .
                 "you can do so at <a href='http://www.google.com/recaptcha/mailhide/apikey'>http://www.google.com/recaptcha/mailhide/apikey</a>");
        }

        $ky = pack('H*', $privkey);
        $cryptmail = _recaptcha_aes_encrypt ($email, $ky);

        return "http://www.google.com/recaptcha/mailhide/d?k=" .
               $pubkey .
               "&c=" .
               _recaptcha_mailhide_urlbase64 ($cryptmail);
    }

    /**
     * Gets the parts of the email to expose to the user.
     * for example, given johndoe@example.com return ["john", "example.com"].
     * the email is then displayed as john...@example.com
     */
    function _recaptcha_mailhide_email_parts ($email) {
        $arr = preg_split("/@/", $email);

        if (strlen ($arr[0]) <= 4) {
            $arr[0] = substr ($arr[0], 0, 1);
        }
        else if (strlen ($arr[0]) <= 6) {
            $arr[0] = substr ($arr[0], 0, 3);
        }
        else {
            $arr[0] = substr ($arr[0], 0, 4);
        }
        return $arr;
    }

    /**
     * Gets HTML to display an email address given a public
     * an private key. To get a key, go to:
     *
     * http://www.google.com/recaptcha/mailhide/apikey
     */
    function recaptcha_mailhide_html($pubkey, $privkey, $email) {
        $emailparts = _recaptcha_mailhide_email_parts ($email);
        $url = recaptcha_mailhide_url ($pubkey, $privkey, $email);

        return htmlentities($emailparts[0]) .
               "<a href='" . htmlentities ($url) .
               "' onclick=\"window.open('" .
               htmlentities ($url) .
               "', '', 'toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,location=0,statusbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=0,width=500,height=300'); return false;\" title=\"Reveal this e-mail address\">...</a>@" .
               htmlentities ($emailparts [1]);
    }
?>
```

I need assistance upgrading this to V2. I want to do this via PHP if possible, but I am struggling to find out what I need to replace, etc.

How can I do this?

Comment: You could redo the code and try this link: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display